# How do I do a regex only the specific selection between two tags?

Tags: html, regex, bash, sed, pcre

There have been dozens of similar questions that was asked but my question is about a specific selection between the tags. I don't want the entire selection from `<a href` to `</a>`, I only need to target the `">` between those tags itself.

I am trying to convert `a href` links into wikilinks. For example, if the sample text has:

```
<a href="./light.html">Light</a> is light.

<div class="reasons">
```

I wanted to edit the file itself and change from `<a href="link.html">Link</a>` into `[[link.html|Link]]`. The basic idea that I have right now uses 3 sed edits as follows:

1. `<a href="link.html">Link</a>` -> `<a href="link.html|Link</a>`
2. `<a href="link.html|Link</a>` -> `[[link.html|Link</a>`
3. `[[link.html|Link</a>` -> `[[link.html|Link]]`

My problem lies with the first step; I can't find the regex that only targets `">` between `<a href` and `</a>`.

I understand that the basic idea would need to be the search target between lookaround and lookbehind. But trying it on regexr showed a fail. I also tried using conditional regex. I can't find the syntax I used but it either turned an error or it worked but it also captured the div class.

Edit: I'm on Ubuntu and using a bash script using sed to do the text manipulation.

Comment: Use DOM manipulation: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/d2gjfnar/ `const wikiLinks = [...document.querySelectorAll("A")].map(lnk => \`[${lnk.href} ${lnk.textContent}\`);`

Comment: im sorry, but this isnt the answer that i am looking for. I wanted a regex as i plan on using it in a script.

Comment: What kind of script? I provided a script you can use in a script. Please be more specific what environment you are planning to use and know that node.js also can use DOM

Comment: I'm on ubuntu so I am using bash currently. If there is a more viable way then I am open to the alternatives. I wanted to edit the file itself and change from `<a href="link.html">Link</a>` into `[[link.html|Link]]`

Comment: _Include a tag for one specific engine or language (perl, pcre, c#, etc). 
Show the pattern that isn't working.
Provide examples of input text that should and shouldn't match.
Describe the desired results and how the pattern isn't producing them_

Comment: Will your anchor tag have any other attributes such as title, classes or id's?  Will your HTML code use single or double quotes around attribute values, or either interchangably?

Comment: `xsltproc` can read html files. This sounds like a job for a stylesheet.

Comment: `sed 's///'` can do that, so does `awk`

Comment: @Martin no, the `<a href="link.html">Link</a>` is a standard template for the files. Always double quotes.
@Nic3500 yes, and I couldn't get a regex that targets the `">` between the `<a href` and `</a>`

Comment: @TKFlagrante a regex that does what you desire: `/<a href=\"(.+)\">([a-z0-9_\s-]+)<\/a>/gmiU --> \[\[{1}\|{2}\]\]` (How to insert replacements depends on the interface so I've give given you the raw regex here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The basic idea that I have right now uses 3 sed edits*

Assuming you've also read the answers underneath those dozens of similar questions, you could've known that [it's a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) [to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) [with `sed` (regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105).

With an HTML-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) this would be as simple as:

```
$ xidel -s '<a href="link.html">Link</a>' -e 'concat("[[",//a/@href,"|",//a,"]]")'
$ xidel -s '<a href="link.html">Link</a>' -e '"[["||//a/@href||"|"||//a||"]]"'
$ xidel -s '<a href="link.html">Link</a>' -e 'x"[[{//a/@href}|{//a}]]"'
[[link.html|Link]]
```

Three different queries to concatenate strings. The 1<sup>st</sup> query uses the [XPath concat() function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-concat), the 2<sup>nd</sup> query uses the [XPath `||` operator](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-string-concat-expr) and the 3<sup>rd</sup> uses `xidel`'s extended string syntax.

Comment: thank you! the problem in of itself worked out nicely. thanks for telling me about xidel. However, is the selective capturing between two tags virtually impossible? I can think of a few use cases, if that is possible via regex

Comment: @TKFlagrante I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "selective capturing"?

Comment: I meant the original question. A different but similar application would be `A man made the mad man in a box` where i only want the `man` between `made` and `box`

Comment: Your description is really poor. So this will be guesswork. Do you mean something like `xidel -s '<a href="link.html">A man made the mad man in a box</a>' -e 'x"[[{//a/@href}|{tokenize(//a)[6]}]]"'`?